# How to find the total number of pages in pdf file loaded in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, pdf

Is there any way to determine the total number of pages once the pdf file is loaded in the ipad? I am using CATiledLayer Method for loading the pdf file.

Thanking you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call the function `size_t CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(CGPDFDocumentRef document);`

See the [CGPDFDocument documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFDocument/Reference/reference.html) for other useful stuff you will probably need.

```
         CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath (NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",filePath], kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, 0);
        CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(url);
        CGPDFPageRef myPageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, 1);
        int  totalPages= CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdf);
```

Comment: Thank you Altealice for your quick help.

Comment: NSURL *pdfURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"alice.pdf" withExtension:nil];
    CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);
    int pageCount = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdf);

Answer (score 4):

Okay Thanks Altealice.I implemented in this manner and i am able to find the number of pages.

Using the following code:

```
NSString *pathToPdfDoc = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mypdf" ofType:@"pdf"];    
NSURL *pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToPdfDoc];   
CGPDFDocumentRef document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfUrl); 
size_t pageCount = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(document);
```

Comment: @zaheer this solution is not use for "https" url.Have you any solution for that?